# Persistent HTTP GET variables in PHP

Tags: php, http, get, methods

Let's say I have some code like this

```
if(isset($_GET['foo']))
  //do something

if(isset($_GET['bar']))
  //do something else
```

If a user is at example.com/?foo=abc and clicks on a link to set bar=xyz, I want to easily take them to example.com/?foo=abc&bar=xyz, rather than example.com/?bar=xyz.

I can think of a few very messy ways to do this, but I'm sure there's something cleaner that I don't know about and haven't been able to track down via Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way....

```
//get passed params
//(you might do some sanitizing at this point)
$params=$_GET;

//morph the params with new values
$params['bar']='xyz';

//build new query string
$query='';
$sep='?';
foreach($params as $name=>$value)
{
    $query.=$sep.$name.'='.urlencode($value);
    $sep='&';
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Although you could have used  http_build_query to build the query. bravo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the query string you need ot make sure you don't do something like

```
$qs="a=1&b=2";
$href="$qs&b=4";
$href contains "a=1&b=2&b=4"
```

What you really want to do is overwrite the current key if you need to . 
You can use a function like this. (disclaimer: Off the top of my head, maybe slightly bugged)

```
    function getUpdateQS($key,$value)
    {
       foreach ($_GET as $k => $v)
       {
            if ($k != $key)
            {
                $qs .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&"
            }
            else
            {
                $qs .= "$key=".urlencode($value)."&";
            }
        }
        return $qs
    }

    <a href="reports.php?<?getupdateqs('name','byron');?">View report</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the link that changes bar to xyz to also have foo=abc if foo is already set.

```
$link = ($_GET['foo'] == 'abc') ? 'foo=abc&bar=xyz' : 'bar=xyz';
?>
<a href="whatever.php?<?= $link ?>">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to render out the links with the proper URL querystring to make that happen.  This is a design decision that you would need to make on your end depending on how your system is setup.

I have some sites that have this issue, and what I do is setup a querystring global variable that sets the current page data the top of the page request.

Then when I am rendering the page, if I need to make use of the current query string I do something like:

```
echo '<a href="myurl.php' . querystring . '&bar=foo';
```

It's not the cleanest, but it all depends on how your system works.

Answer (score 0):

Save some code and use the built-in [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).  I use this wrapper in one of my projects:

```
function to_query_string($array) {
    if(is_scalar($array)) $query = trim($array, '? \t\n\r\0\x0B'); // I could split on "&" and "=" do some urlencode-ing here
    else $query = http_build_query($array);
    return '?'.$query;
}
```

Also, though it isn't often used, you can have $_GET on the left-hand side of an assignment:

```
$_GET['overriden_or_new'] = 'new_value';
echo '<a href="'.to_query_string($_GET).'">Yeah!</a>';
```

Other than that, just do what Paul Dixon said.